# Pivot query not run due to slash (/) in key name

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot-table

In the following Pivot query (which works except for this problem), one of the key values (`Address/Media`) that needs to turn into a column has a slash in its name.

```
SELECT dimOriginKey,Address/Media,Lottery,NumContactsProcessed,CostRound,Campaign,Supplier,Cost,NumContacts FROM 
(
    SELECT dimOriginKey,measureValueNum,measureKey FROM dimOrigin o
    JOIN dimOriginMeasure om ON o.originSNKey = om.originSNKey
    WHERE om.measureValueMissing = 'n' AND om.measureValueNum IS NOT NULL
) src PIVOT 
(
MAX(measurevaluenum)
FOR measurekey IN (Address/Media,Lottery,NumContactsProcessed,CostRound,Campaign,Supplier,Cost,NumContacts)
) PIV;
```

This causes the query to throw the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '/'.

How can I fix this so that `Address/Media` shows up in the result column as well as the others?

**NB.** I know it was probably not very smart to enter a slash in the value, but I'm afraid I cannot change the database.

Comment: Try this `[Address/Media]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your column names with square brackets - `[Address/Media]`.  This tells SQL Server that everything in between is to be treated as the column/table name and not as an operator.

Comment: Correct! Thank you. Will choose it as answer as soon as Stack Overflow lets me.